# Use newer version of botocore in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, serverless-framework, botocore

I'd like to use the Boto3 [put_bucket_encryption](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_encryption) inside a lambda function, but the current [Lambda execution enviornment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) is at botocore version 1.7.37, and the [put_bucket_encryption](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_encryption) was introduced in botocore [1.7.41](https://github.com/boto/botocore/commit/b0e23dbe9c95e5030ffc788a9617040fe7539904).

So I'd like to package up my local version of boto3/botocore.

I've included pip packages in lambda functions using [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/framework/), along with [serverless-python-requirements](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements), but it doesn't seem to work for boto3/botocore.

The function responds to a `CreateBucket` event and tries to [put_bucket_encryption](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_encryption), but fails with

```
'S3' object has no attribute 'put_bucket_encryption': AttributeError
```

How can I force my lambda function to use a more up to date botocore?

Comment: I think the instructions for `serverless-python-requirements` suggest using `#nodeploy` in your `requrements.txt` file. That would cause your local boto3 to not be uploaded.

Comment: That's it.  Missed the section in the docs on [omitting-packages](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#omitting-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve with kichik's help

What I missed was the section about [omitting packages](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#omitting-packages) in the [serverless-python-requirements](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements) docs. Specifically:

> By default, this will not install the AWS SDKs that are already installed on Lambda.

So in my `serverless.yml` I added

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    noDeploy:
      - pytest
```

Once I deployed, it was using my packaged versions of boto3/botocore